# Pandas - Sum values in list according to index from another list

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, numpy

I am trying to find the most pythonic way to tackle down my problem in the short time as possible since I am dealing with a large amount of data. My problem is the following:

I have two lists

```
a = [12,34,674,2,0,5,6,8]
b = ['foo','bar','bar','foo','foo','bar','foo','foo']
```

I want to say python: if 'bar' is in b, take all the indexes and sum all values in list a with those indexes.

This is what I have done so far:

```
idx = [i for i, j in enumerate(a) if j == 'bar']
```

but then I am stacked. I am considering using some wired for loops. Do you have any idea?

Comment: sum([a[i] for i, j in enumerate(b) if j == 'bar'] ).. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)

a[b == 'bar'].sum()
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `np.bincount`. Computes both sums ('foo' and 'bar').

```
sum_foo, sum_bar = np.bincount(np.char.equal(b, 'bar'), a)
sum_foo
# 28.0
sum_bar
# 713.0
```

Note `np.char.equal` works on both lists and arrays. If b is an array, then `b == 'bar'` can be used instead and is a bit faster.

Timings:

Even though this computes both sums it is actually pretty fast:

```
timeit(lambda: np.bincount(b == 'bar', a))
# 2.406161994993454
```

Compare for example with the numpy masking method:

```
timeit(lambda: a[b == 'bar'].sum())
# 5.642918559984537
```

On larger arrays masking becomes slightly faster which is expected since `bincount` does essentially 2x the work. Still `bincount` takes less than 2x the time, so if you happen to need both sums ('foo' and 'bar'), `bincount` is still faster.

```
aa = np.repeat(a, 1000)
bb = np.repeat(b, 1000)
timeit(lambda: aa[bb == 'bar'].sum(), number=1000)
# 0.07860603698645718
timeit(lambda:np.bincount(bb == 'bar', aa), number=1000)
# 0.11229897901648656
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple to do in `pandas`:

```
In[5]:
import pandas as pd
a = [12,34,674,2,0,5,6,8]
b = ['foo','bar','bar','foo','foo','bar','foo','foo']
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b})
df

Out[5]: 
     a    b
0   12  foo
1   34  bar
2  674  bar
3    2  foo
4    0  foo
5    5  bar
6    6  foo
7    8  foo

In [8]: df.loc[df['b']=='bar','a'].sum()
Out[8]: 713
```

So here we take your lists and construct a `dict` in place for the `data` arg for the `DataFrame` ctor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b})
```

Then we just mask the df using `loc` where we select the rows where `'b' == 'bar'` and select the column `'a'` and call `sum()`:

```
df.loc[df['b']=='bar','a'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
l = [x for x,y in zip(a,b) if y == 'bar']
```

If you want indexes:

```
l = [i for (i,x),y in zip(enumerate(a),b) if y == 'bar']
```